# Proving the base case for a problem in elementary number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I have a question about how to prove statements such as the following, using induction:

> If $p \mid a_1a_2 \cdots a_k$, then $p \mid a_i$ for some $i$, $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$, where $p$ is prime.

For the base case, we have to show that $p \mid a_1$. But we don't know anything about $p$ or $a_1$, so how would that work?

The author of my textbook says that "$P(1)$ is true by inspection if $k = 1$." I'm not sure how that is possible.

Comment: The base case is $\ p\mid a_1\Rightarrow p\mid a_1\ \ $

Comment: What @BillDubuque says is quite different from just "$p|a_1$". In other words, you don't have to show "$p|a_1$", but rather you have to show "$p|a_1 \Rightarrow p|a_1$". And that *is* obvious, isn't it?